# Determine if Finder can be safely killed

Tags: swift, macos, swift2, finder

I am currently developing a utility program that requires the Finder to be restarted after some changes are made to the user's defaults.

To be on the safe side, I would like to check if the Finder is busy before calling `killall Finder` (via `NSTask`). If the Finder is copying files or otherwise busy, I would like to prevent the action and wait a little.

Is there a way to determine if the Finder is busy or if it can safely be killed, in Swift 2.3 on macOS 10.10+ ?

In case this is not possible, is there a safer way for me to refresh (restart) the Finder?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want to forcibly kill it, rather than send a quit event followed by an activate one?

Comment: I didn't know that was actually possible. Should I use AppleScript for this? Can you post an example as answer? That would help me

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10226948/4573247) can help you out (obj-C, Cocoa). Alternatively, using AppleScript, see if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1462686/4573247) can help you out (obj-C, AppleScript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @dfri 's comment, I was able to figure out a way (albeit not exactly the one presented in the linked answer) to do this.

Since observing the `NSRunningApplication` object for the Finder was not possible (the object was `deinit`ialized due to termination before I could remove the observer), I ended up observing `NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification` from `NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().notificationCenter`

```
NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyController.applicationWasTerminated(_:)), name: NSWorkspaceDidTerminateApplicationNotification, object: nil)
```

I can then remove this observer when my controller is `deinit`ialized, and the selector looks like this :

```
func applicationWasTerminated(notification: NSNotification?) {
    guard let notif = notification else { return }
    guard let userInfo = notif.userInfo as? [String : AnyObject] else { return }
    guard let identifier = userInfo["NSApplicationBundleIdentifier"] as? String else { return }
    if identifier == "com.apple.finder" {
        NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().launchAppWithBundleIdentifier("com.apple.finder", options: NSWorkspaceLaunchOptions.Default, additionalEventParamDescriptor: nil, launchIdentifier: nil)
    }
}
```